# Ancestor of a comment object

Tags: vba, ms-word, comments, ancestor

I wanted to find the ancestor of a specified comment object using VBA and have written the code.

```
Dim oComment as Comment
Set oComment = ActiveDocument.Comments.Item(1)
If (oComment.Ancestor = Null) Then
MsgBox (ActiveDocument.Comments(1).Contact & " has added a new comment")
Else
MsgBox (ActiveDocument.Comments(1).Contact & " has replied to a comment")
End If
```

But it is giving me the error as Object variable not set (Error 91)

I am trying in Word VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for `oComment.Ancestor is nothing` as `Ancestor` is an object